# Android Background Task Selection

Tags: android, kotlin

I have an Android "shopping cart" app for business customers to place orders (business-to-business).  I'd like a task to run in the background to synchronize items and orders.  But I'm having trouble figuring out which of the many options for background tasks I should use (Async Task, Service, Sync Adapter, Jetpack Work Manager, etc).

First, some background notes:

- We are providing the Android phones to customers.
- The phones are running Android 6 (API 23)
- I am not concerned about battery life, since these phones will only be in use for an hour (or less) at a time.
- The background processing doesn't need to run outside the scope of the application because the application will always be open (I am planning for it to be the default launcher).

Here are my requirements:

- Some sync tasks should run every few seconds (orders), other sync tasks should run every half hour (item updates).
- The app needs to be able to stop and restart the background syncing on specific user events (like deleting & recreating the sqlite database)
- There should only be ONE sync process running at a time.

Optionally it would be nice to have:

- The background task notify the application when an order has been uploaded.
- The sync process shutdown cleanly (allow it to finish out a sync cycle) instead of just being killed.
- If the application could send a message to the background sync then it could initiate the on-demand order sync eliminating the need for the background process to keep checking the database files for a new order every few seconds.  (I would still want the periodic 30-min sync to run for lower-priority item synchronization).

Anyone have anything that they'd like to share on what they'd recommend?  I am wondering if I should just have a process running in the background all of the time.  That way it can control the timing with sleep statements processing some syncs every few seconds and others every half hour.  So would this make sense to be a service?

I certainly appreciate the input!  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to go with a ScheduledExecutorService.  Whether this is the best option or not, I don't know.  But it did give me what I most needed:

- Only one instance running at a time.
- I can start and stop as needed.
- It does run out side of the scope of the application (which I didn't really need but it could be nice to have)
- I have the Runnable Class continuing to loop checking a Preference Boolean when I want it to terminate.
- I have a sleep of a few seconds in between loops.  So every few seconds I check to see if there are any SQLite records to process.
- For my processes which I only want to run less frequently I just have a counter to keep track of the number of sleep cycles executed since the last time these processes were run.
- While I'm sure that there are some more battery-friendly options, I don't really think that this will consume too much battery (nor do I really need to care for this specific application)
- WorkManager seemed to not work for me because I couldn't have long-running processes (over 10 minutes) and I wanted my background task to constantly run.

While I think that I have a working configuration, I am still open to any thoughts that anyone would like to share.

Thanks!